# How to correctly formulate a sum function with range in excel

Tags: excel

I'd like to write this function in excel:

[image]

It's a function that calculated how much experience is needed for a particular level.
level 2 is 83xp, level 99 is over 13,000,000 for example.

I have all the levels arranged in this way:

[image]

I just can't figure out the excel formula to put into cell 4B to calculate the function in the image. I'm thinking it should be something like

`=floor(sum[1 to cellToLeft.value - 1](floor(x + 300*2^(x/7))/4))` 
but that's not quite right

Comment: you can do it in two steps.  step one eveluate your formula for just the cell to the left.  set up the equation referring to the cell where 1 is.  when you can evaluate properly for that cell, copy the formula down.  It should update the cell reference as you go down.  This will leave you with a column of value for a single instance.   Step two would be to sum the column to the point that corresponds to L-1

Comment: you could also try an array formula like so `{=floor(sum(floor(A4:A14 + 300*2^(A4:A14/7))/4))}`  That would be for the case of L=12

Comment: Thanks guys that works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
{=FLOOR(SUM(FLOOR(R4C[-1]:RC[-1]+300*2^(R4C[-1]:RC[-1]/7),1))/4,1)}
```

Make sure you enter as an array formula.

If you don't use R1C1 mode then you need something like this:

```
{=FLOOR(SUM(FLOOR(A$4:A12+300*2^(A$4:A12/7),1))/4,1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be an array formula in excel answer.  Place the level you want (the value for L) in N4, or change the reference to suit your needs.  Enter the following formula in the cell you want the answer to be in remembering to press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when finishing the formula instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  You will know you have done it right when {} appear around your formula in Excel.

```
=FLOOR(SUM(FLOOR(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,$N$4-1))+300*2^(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,$N$4-1))/7),1)/4),1)
```

[image: POC1]
[image: POC2]

Level 1 will cause an error since L-1=0.  Since I am assuming it takes 0 for level 1, I threw in a error trap.  anytime the formula returns an error it give a value of 0 instead.  With the following formula you can change the $N4 reference to where ever you have your level 1 value.  remember to use C+S+E when you enter the formula and copy downward as far as your levels go.

```
=IFERROR(FLOOR(SUM(FLOOR(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,$N4-1))+300*2^(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,$N4-1))/7),1)/4),1),0)
```